# Searching multiple words in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a code like this:

```
string = 'algorithms, c, software design, oop, java, software engineering, data structures, satellite, python, mobile, infrastructure, .net'
enter = input('Enter search: ')

if enter in string:
    print('Yes, it is in there')
```

This works when i search a singular word such as 'python' or 'oop', etc.

I want to be able to search for multiple words in that string.
Suppose like "algorithms, oop", it should return the true value. Now its just showing nothing since it cannot find exactly "algorithms, oop" in the string. But i don't want this to be the case so if anybody can help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can split the input sentence by comma (,) and then search for individual terms.. If not found we will exit otherwise if all are found just print
'Yes, its in there'

```
string = 'algorithms, c, software design, oop, java, software engineering, data structures, satellite, python, mobile, infrastructure, .net'
enter = input('Enter search: ')

for word in enter.split(","):
    if word not in string:
        exit()
print('Yes, it is in there')
```

Comment: You need to run ``.strip()`` on ``word`` since the leading/trailing whitespace creates unexpected search misses.

Answer (score 0):

try use this:

```
string = 'algorithms, c, software design, oop, java, software engineering, data structures, satellite, python, mobile, infrastructure, .net'


word_dict = {word.strip(): True for word in 
string.split(',')}


enter = input('Enter search terms (comma-separated): ')



search_terms = [term.strip() for term in enter.split(',')]


if all(term in word_dict for term in search_terms):

    print('Yes, all search terms are in there')

else:

    print('Not all search terms are present')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `if/else`

snippet:

```
string ='algorithms, c, software design, oop, java, software engineering, data structures, satellite, python, mobile, infrastructure, .net'
enter = input('Enter search: ')

if enter in string:
    print('Yes, it is in there')
else:
    print('No, it is in there')
```

Output:

```
Enter search: tkinter
No, it is in there


Enter search: python
Yes, it is in there
```